# Custom Planedetector on Sceneform without repeating

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arcore, sceneform

I want to create a pointer on the plane which shows exactly where the object will be placed.

The way I tried to do so is by using my pointer's image as custom Planedetector Image.

The problem is its repeating my image creating a pattern.
I tried changing the wrap properties but no use. Its still repeating.

Is there any other way you'd recommend to make a pointer on sceneform?

Answer (score 0):

The Planedetector image will generally expand to cover the plane as I think you have seen so is likely not the easiest approach.

One way to do this is to make the pointer itself a renderable object and place it on the plane first.

You can then delete and replica it with the object you eventually want to place there once the user has confirmed the location.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did it.

You need to just turn or remove line for wraper property repeat mode like bellow

```
private fun updatePlanDetection() {
        val sampler = Texture.Sampler.builder()
            .setMinFilter(Texture.Sampler.MinFilter.LINEAR)
            .build()

        Texture.builder()
            .setSource(this, R.drawable.ic_target)
            .setSampler(sampler)
            .build()
            .thenAccept { texture ->

                arFragment.arSceneView.planeRenderer
                    .material.thenAccept { material ->
                        material.setTexture(
                            PlaneRenderer.MATERIAL_TEXTURE,
                            texture
                        )
                        material.setFloat(PlaneRenderer.MATERIAL_SPOTLIGHT_RADIUS, 50F);
                    }
            }
    }
```

But there is one issue, currently I cant enlarge my image